# Is this safe? Rvalue and reference return values

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, rvalue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Wrapper
{
public:
    std::string&& get() &&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
        return std::move(str);
    }

    const std::string& get() const &
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
        return str;
    }
private:
    std::string str;
};

std::string foo()
{
    Wrapper wrap;
    return wrap.get();
}

std::string bar()
{
    Wrapper wrap;
    return std::move(wrap.get());
}

std::string fooRvalue()
{
    return Wrapper().get();
}

std::string barRvalue()
{
    return std::move(Wrapper().get());
}

int main() {
    while(1)
    {
        std::string s = foo();
        std::string s2 = bar();
        std::string s3 = fooRvalue();
        std::string s4 = barRvalue();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is the return value of const std::string&, and std::string&& safe in this use case (pretend std::string is some other type that may be not copyable). I thought it would not work because the refernce should point to some local variable which would go out of scope, but it appears to work just fine? Also i've seen the && syntax used before, did i use it correctly (i restricted it to when Wrapper is itself an rvalue).

Im just a little generally confused when returning a reference is safe, i thought the rule was that the object had to outlive the value being returned but i've seen things like the standard library and boost returing reference before. If i store the reference they give me in a variable (that is not a reference) it all seems to work just fine if i then return that stored variable. Can someone fix me up, and give me some good rules to follow.

Here's the ideone i was playing around with, it all seems to work: http://ideone.com/GyWQF6

Comment: If I remember correctly, then `for (char c : Wrapper{}.get()) { ... }` would be unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct and safe way of implementing a member getter.  But you could make one improvement, which I'll get to.  The key is that the lifetime of the `std::string` member is (almost) the same as the lifetime of the `Wrapper` object which contains it.  And a temporary is only destroyed at the end of the full-expression where it appears, not immediately after it's "used".  So in `return std::move(Wrapper().get());`, the `Wrapper` is created, `get()` is called, `std::move` is called, the return value is constructed, and only then the `Wrapper` and its `string` are destroyed.

The only danger is if somebody binds another reference to your member.  But that would be their mistake, and ordinary const-reference getters have the same danger.  This is the equivalent of the incorrect `const char* ptr = "oops"s.c_str();`.

```
std::string foo()
{
    Wrapper wrap;
    return wrap.get();
}
```

`foo` copy constructs the return value from the member.  Hopefully that's not a surprise.

```
std::string bar()
{
    Wrapper wrap;
    return std::move(wrap.get());
}
```

`bar` also copy constructs the return value from the member.  What's going on here is that since `wrap` is an lvalue, the lvalue `get()` is called, which returns a `const` lvalue.  (Informally, "`const std::string&`".)  Then `move` converts that to an xvalue, but it's still `const`.  (Informally, "`const std::string&&`".)  The move constructor `string(string&&)` cannot match here, since the argument is `const`.  But the copy constructor `string(const string&)` can match, and is called.

If you expected `bar` to move construct the return value, you may want to add a third overload for non-const lvalues:

```
std::string& get() & { return str; }
```

(If you didn't want to allow modifying the member, note that you already sort of did.  For example, somebody could do `std::move(wrap).get() = "something";`.)

Also, if you had `return std::move(wrap).get();` instead, that would have move constructed the return value even without the third overload.

```
std::string fooRvalue()
{
    return Wrapper().get();
}
```

`fooRvalue` move constructs the return value, since the rvalue `get()` is used.  As already mentioned, the `Wrapper` lives long enough for this construction to be safe.

```
std::string barRvalue()
{
    return std::move(Wrapper().get());
}
```

In `barRvalue`, the `move` call is absolutely useless.  The expression `Wrapper().get()` is already an xvalue, so `move` just converts an xvalue of type `std::string` to ... an xvalue of type `std::string`.  Still just as safe, though.

Comment: Your answer is quite amazing. Few questions, when does an rvalue or an lvalue turn into an xvalue. And two you mentioned, "If you expected bar to move construct the return value, you may want to add a third overload for non-const lvalues". Now i don't totally follow why someone is allowed to modify the const reference I returned (it's supposed to be const, right?), but knowing now that they can would it be better to just return a non-const reference instead of a const reference (as i do want bar to move construct)

Comment: `std::move` is used to turn any expression into an xvalue.  (You could also cast to an rvalue reference type, but `move` is more convenient.)  Nobody is allowed to modify the const reference you returned, _if_ that const lvalue overload is used.  The trick in `std::move(wrap).get() = "something";` is using the other overload instead.  Note that if you had a `const Wrapper` object to begin with, there's no way to modify the member.

Comment: One last question, appreciate this. Lets say wrapper holds unique_ptr (non copy-able) and that i drop the const qualifier so that get now looks like `std::unique_ptr& get()`. If a user of this wrapper writes code like this (so that get is called twice in a row), `auto contents = wrap.get() auto contents2 = wrap.get()` the contents variable would be moved into correct? And since the lvalue get() is called twice a move would happen twice and cause bad things?

Comment: `auto contents = wrap.get();` would not compile, since the lvalue returned cannot bind to an rvalue reference for the move constructor, and the copy constructor is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The return value object of a function will be initialized *before* the destruction of local variables and temporaries created in the `return` expression. As such, it is perfectly legitimate to move from locals/temporaries into function return values.

Those four global functions work because they return objects, not references to objects. And that object gets constructed before any of the locals that their constructor parameter reference are destroyed.

`barRvalue` is rather redundant (since the result of `Wrapper().get()` is already an rvalue reference), but functional.

> Im just a little generally confused when returning a reference is safe

A function returning a reference to an object *that has been destroyed* is what is unsafe. Returning a reference to a local object, or part of a local object, is unsafe.

Returning a reference to `*this` or some part of `*this` is safe, because the `this` object will outlive the function that returns the reference. It's no different from returning a reference to a parameter that you take by pointer/reference. The object will outlive the function call that returns the reference.

Comment: "returning a reference to a local variable or part of a local variable, is unsafe". Isn't the .get() method of wrapper a part of a local variable? The wrapper should only live while that function lives, is the return value of .get() being copied?

Comment: @StephenEckels: `this` is not a local variable; it is an implicit parameter passed in to every non-static member function. It refers to the object being invoked, and unless the member function directly destroys the object, that object is guaranteed to exist after the reference is returned.